# Rails - Cannot get Rspec click link to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

Hey I am doing `click_link` in rspec rails then checking the linked page for content. The content **is definitely on that page** but it's still giving me an error that it is not.

**The error**

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('h1', :text => "Reset Password")
```

This is what my spec is doing

1. Visits log_in_path
2. clicks forgotten password
3. which in effect visits new_password_reset_path
4. looks for `<h1>` Reset Password `</h1>`

**password_resets_controller_spec.rb (the spec)**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PasswordResetsController do
    it "emails user when requesting password reset" do
        user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        visit log_in_path
        click_link "forgotten password?"
        current_path.should eq(new_password_reset_path)
        page.should have_selector('h1', :text => "Reset Password")
    end
end
```

**new.html.haml (log_in_path)**

```
%h1 Log in

= form_tag sessions_path do
  %p
    = label_tag :email
    = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
  %p
    = label_tag :password
    = password_field_tag :password
  %p.button
    %input{name: "commit", type: "submit", value: "Log in"}
  .field
    = label_tag :remember_me
    = check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me]
  %p
    = link_to "forgotten password?", new_password_reset_path
```

**new.html.haml (the page it should go to after clicking link)**

```
%h1 Reset Password

= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do
  .field
    = label_tag :email
    = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
  .actions
    = submit_tag "Reset Password"
```

**routes.rb**

```
SomeApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "password_resets/new"
  get "sessions/new"
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :email_activations
  resources :users do
    collection do 
      get :accept_invitation
    end 
  end
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match "sign_up",  to: "users#new"
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/log_in',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/log_out', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your test code is in a controller spec instead of an integration spec. What you have in the spec file is an integration test, not a controller test. Page and visit are part of the capybara dsl and are not available in controller specs. it should either be in spec/requests directory for older versions of rspec-rails and capybara, or the spec/features directory if you are using rspec-rails ~> 2.11.1 & capybara ~>2.0.0beta.

source: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md

Update:

Since you are using an older version of capybara, rename and move your spec file to

`someapp/spec/requests/password_resets_spec.rb`

or you could even run the generator and it will put it in the right directory and file name

`rails generate integration_test password_reset`

Comment: The code looks fine for an integration test. What version of rspec-rails and capybara are you using?

Comment: I tried that and i get. Failure/Error: visit log_in_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_7:0

Comment: rails 3.2.13  and capybara 1.1.2

Comment: What version of rspec-rails are you using in your Gemfile?

Comment: In another comment you said the full path of your spec file was someapp/spec/controllers/password_resets_controller_spec.rb. This is your problem. Create a requests directory if you dont already have one, like this someapp/spec/requests/password_resets_controller_spec.rb. Really you should also take controller out of the spec name and call it password_resets_spec.rb

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have in your settings Capybara.default_selector set to :css. Try this code:

```
page.find('h1', :text => "Reset Password")
```

This has the same effect, as it uses Capybara to find your element. Find() will raise an exception if the selector is not found

Read more: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders

Comment: with that it says Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "h1"

Comment: What's the directory path of your password_resets_controller_spec.rb file?

Comment: someapp/app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb

Comment: no, the _spec file. rspec have a conventional way to run your specs according to the location of your _spec file. if it's in the wrong directory, the views are not rendered, so the finder will always return an error. Is your `password_resets_controller_spec.rb` file in your `spec/features` directory?

Comment: someapp/spec/controllers/password_resets_controller_spec.rb

Comment: That's a wrong path. `someapp/spec/controllers/*_spec.rb` is good to unit test your controllers. Move your `password_resets_controller_spec.rb` file to `someapp/spec/features` directory and try again

Comment: interesting now it wont visit my log_in path   Failure/Error: visit log_in_path       NoMethodError:    undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_7:0xa7bdab8>

Comment: Yes, you should use `get` instead of `visit`. Rspec is full of conventions, you should study them https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Failure/Error: get log_in_path    ActionController::RoutingError:
 No route matches {:controller=>"password_resets", :action=>"/log_in"}

Comment: use `get '/log_in'`. Please read the pages I link, you have full info there, I can really help you line by line :)

Comment: when i write get /log_in or get/log_in_path   it gives me an error when i run rspec      Failure/Error: get log_in_path
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"password_resets", :action=>"/log_in"}